# How to append JSON object to existing JSON object in JS file in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a Todo app using *React.js*.

I took todo data from an in-app js file as a JSON object. I want to add more todo in my list which I want to store in that js file as a JSON object.

I want to append another JSON object with existing. How can I do it?

TodoList.js file

```js
const TodoList=
   [

    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Learn backbone",
      "complete": false,
      "canceled": false,
      "date": new Date().getTime()
    },

    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Go for a run",
      "complete": false,
      "canceled": false,
      "date": new Date().getTime()
    }
  ]

  export default TodoList;
```

New TodoList.js file should be like this:

```js
const TodoList=
[

    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Learn backbone",
      "complete": false,
      "canceled": false,
      "date": new Date().getTime()
    },

    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Go for a run",
      "complete": false,
      "canceled": false,
      "date": new Date().getTime()
    },

    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Have Lunch",
      "complete": true,
      "canceled": false,
      "date": new Date().getTime() 
    }
  ]

  export default TodoList
```

Comment: Your `TodoList` const is an array. You can either use spread operator or use `TodoList.push(newTodo)`. This is more of a Javascript question than a react tho.

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with React, this is plain object/array manipulation in Javascript. If you want to take an existing array and add a new element, simply have:

```
const newToDoList = [...toDoList, {"id": 3, ...}]
```

You spread the previous array and create a new one with a new element.